# View is returning an HttpResponse, but says it returns None

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a button in one of my views that triggers a function "compileUpdate" and then returns a file as a response. This was working previously but now I receive the error:

"ValueError: The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

The block of code below essentially:
Gets the correct campaign
Formats the path of the files to compile
Checks if a specific directory exists, and if not creates it
Calls the compileUpdate function
Returns the file as a http response

**Non-working file creation and response**

```
if req == "Bulk Update":
            cmp_id = request.headers.get('cmp')

            campaign = Campaign.objects.get(id=cmp_id)

            parent_dir = os.path.normpath(os.getcwd() + os.sep + os.pardir)

            submittedFolder = os.path.join(parent_dir, "SubmittedReviews", "", str(cmp_id) + "-" + campaign.system.name, "")

            cmp_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(submittedFolder,'*'))

            archive = os.path.join(parent_dir, "Archive", "", str(campaign.id) + "-" + campaign.system.name, "")

            if os.path.exists(archive) == False:
                os.mkdir(archive)

            bulk_update = os.path.join(archive, str(campaign.id) + "-" + campaign.system.name + "_bulk_update.csv")
            print(bulk_update)
            with open(bulk_update, 'w') as bulk_out:
                writer = csv.writer(bulk_out)

                compileUpdate(cmp_files, campaign, writer)
            bulk_out.close()

            time.sleep(2)

            file = str(bulk_update).split("/")[-1]
            
            with open(bulk_update, 'rb') as fh:
                response = HttpResponse(fh.read())
                response['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="{}"'.format(os.path.basename(bulk_update))
                response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = f'/archive/{file}'
            return response
```

As mentioned above, this errors out saying that I am returning None rather than an http response, however I have another button in a separate view that utilizes this a similar code block to return a file that works just fine. That one looks like:

**Working file creation and response**

```
if file_type == "responses":
            data = request.GET.getlist("campaigns")[0].split(",")
            campaigns = []
            for item in data:
                cmp_id = item.split(' ')[0]
                campaigns.append(Campaign.objects.get(id=cmp_id))
            files = compileResponses(campaigns)
            files = joinFiles(files)
            file = files[0]

            f = str(file).split("/")[-1]

            time.sleep(2)

            with open(file, 'rb') as fh:
                response = HttpResponse(fh.read())
                response['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="{}"'.format(os.path.basename(file))
                response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = f'/archive/{f}'
            return response
```

If I print the first response then I get `<HttpResponse status_code=200, "application/vnd.ms-excel">` so I know that I am actually returning an http resonse.

**Template Script that triggers the view's file creation**:

```
<script>
    function exportData(event) {

        var btn
        btn = event.target
        value = $(btn).parent().parent().parent().find('.export-select').val()
        cmp = $(btn).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('td')[0].textContent
        dict = {}
        
        if (value == "Bulk Update") {
            // Create the Post request, pass the csrf_token in the header of the request
            $.ajax({
                url: '/campaignmanager/download/' + cmp + '/',
                type: 'GET',
                headers: {'X-CSRFtoken': '{{ csrf_token }}', 'data': 'Bulk Update', 'cmp': cmp},
                data: dict,
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        }

        else if (value == "Bulk Delete") {
            // Create the Post request, pass the csrf_token in the header of the request
            $.ajax({
                url: '/campaignmanager/download/' + cmp + '/',
                type: 'GET',
                headers: {'X-CSRFtoken': '{{ csrf_token }}', 'data': 'Bulk Delete', 'cmp': cmp},
                data: dict,
                dataType: 'json'
            })

        }

        else {
            return false;
        }
        
        window.location = "/campaignmanager/download/" + cmp + "/"
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

**Full View**:

```
def campaignManager(request, **kwargs):


    elevated = checkPerms(request)
    sysAdmin = checkAdmin(request)

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')

    elif elevated != True and sysAdmin != True and request.user.is_superuser == False:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')


    if "download" in str(request.path):
        req = request.headers.get('data')

        if req == "Bulk Update":
            cmp_id = request.headers.get('cmp')

            campaign = Campaign.objects.get(id=cmp_id)

            parent_dir = os.path.normpath(os.getcwd() + os.sep + os.pardir)

            submittedFolder = os.path.join(parent_dir, "SubmittedReviews", "", str(cmp_id) + "-" + campaign.system.name, "")

            cmp_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(submittedFolder,'*'))

            archive = os.path.join(parent_dir, "Archive", "", str(campaign.id) + "-" + campaign.system.name, "")

            if os.path.exists(archive) == False:
                os.mkdir(archive)

            bulk_update = os.path.join(archive, str(campaign.id) + "-" + campaign.system.name + "_bulk_update.csv")
            print(bulk_update)
            with open(bulk_update, 'w') as bulk_out:
                writer = csv.writer(bulk_out)

                compileUpdate(cmp_files, campaign, writer)
            bulk_out.close()

            with open(bulk_update, 'r') as bulk:
                reader = csv.DictReader(bulk)
                for row in reader:
                    print(row)
            bulk.close()

            time.sleep(2)

            file = str(bulk_update).split("/")[-1]
            
            with open(bulk_update, 'rb') as fh:
                response = HttpResponse(fh.read())
                response['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="{}"'.format(os.path.basename(bulk_update))
                response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = f'/archive/{file}'
            return response
            


        elif req == "Bulk Delete":
            cmp_id = request.headers.get('cmp')

            campaign = Campaign.objects.get(id=cmp_id)

            pass

    else:
        # Uses campaign manager template
        template = loader.get_template('AccessReview/campaignManager.html')
        # Create empty dict for context
        context = {}

        context['user'] = employee.objects.get(pid__iexact=request.user.username)

        if sysAdmin == True:
            context["parent_template"] = "AccessReview/sysAdminBase.html"
        elif request.user.is_superuser == True:
            context["parent_template"] = "AccessReview/adminbase.html"
        elif elevated == True:
            context["parent_template"] = "AccessReview/elevatedBase.html"

        # Pass campaign and review instances to campaign management template
        context['Campaigns'] = Campaign.objects.all()
        context['Reviews'] = review.objects.all()
        context['Systems'] = System.objects.all()


            

        # Handle campaign creations through POST request
        if request.method == "POST":
            data = request.POST

            req = request.headers.get('data')

            if req == "campaign":

                allowed = checkPerms(request)

                if allowed == True:
                    date = str(data['expectedEndDate']).split("/")[2] + "-" + str(data['expectedEndDate']).split("/")[0] + "-" + str(data['expectedEndDate']).split("/")[1]
                    systemName = data['system']
                    reviewLevel = data['reviewLevel']

                    # Create campaign with the one required value
                    campaign = Campaign.createCampaign(expectedEndDate=date, system=systemName, reviewLevel=reviewLevel)
                    
                    management.debug("%s created a campaign for %s expected to be completed by %s", request.user, systemName, date)
                    time.sleep(1)
                    return redirect('/campaignmanager/')

                else:
                    return redirect('/campaignmanager/')

        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: Can you share full of your view?

Comment: edited to include full view, the rest really isn't relevant as the portion I shared is what is being called when the button is pressed

Answer (score -1):

You did not return anything `if req == "Bulk Delete"`

You should add `HttpResponse` as well.

```
        elif req == "Bulk Delete":
        cmp_id = request.headers.get('cmp')

        campaign = Campaign.objects.get(id=cmp_id)

        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

Comment: Yeah that is why I didn't include the whole view, only Bulk update is being called. Bulk delete isn't being built out until bulk update works properly. Bulk delete is never called